# What is the relationship() function used for in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

While working through the documentation from SQLAlchemy, I can't seem to get an understanding of the purpose of the relationship() function.

I have created a database with and without the relationship() mapping and see no difference in the table definitions at the db level. I also notice no effect on queries through the interactive prompt. No 'children' column is created on the table 'parent'. What is its purpose?

```
 class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Child", backref="parent")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`relationship` does not affect the database schema. It provides a convenient way to access related objects. In this instance it allows you to get all `Child` objects that are related to a `Parent` through the `children` attribute. `backref` then adds a `parent` attribute to all `Child` objects.

By default, related objects will be loaded through a `SELECT` query. By passing `lazy='joined'` to `relationship`, however, the two tables will be joined when querying.

Answer (score 5):

[dirn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27647812/452102) is right. To give some useful examples:

```
session = Session()

# create children in a cool way
parent = Parent(children=[Child(), Child()])
# this will save everybody
session.add(parent)
session.commit()

# get every children of a parent is also simple now
parent = session.query(Parent).one()
print(parent.children)
```